# Scancodes of Fn keys

Tags: linux, keyboard, arch-linux, linux-kernel, wayland

I have a problem with remapping Fn keys on my Dell xps 9370.
Software: Arch linux + Wayland.
I want to remap brightness up/down keys to page up/down, but i cannot find their scancodes. This is output of showkey with pressed brig up key:

```
#>> showkey --scancodes               
kb mode was ?UNKNOWN?
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
0x9c 
0xe0 0x54 0xe0 0xd4
```

Output of evtest:

```
#>> evtest /dev/input/event13 
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x19 vendor 0x0 product 0x6 version 0x0
Input device name: "Video Bus"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN)
    Event code 225 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP)
    Event code 227 (KEY_SWITCHVIDEOMODE)
    Event code 241 (KEY_VIDEO_NEXT)
    Event code 242 (KEY_VIDEO_PREV)
    Event code 243 (KEY_BRIGHTNESS_CYCLE)
    Event code 244 (KEY_BRIGHTNESS_ZERO)
    Event code 245 (KEY_DISPLAY_OFF)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1523197124.754306, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 225 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP), value 1
Event: time 1523197124.754306, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1523197124.754340, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 225 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP), value 0
Event: time 1523197124.754340, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

My hwdb file like this:

```
evdev:*
  KEYBOARD_KEY_d4=pageup
```

I tried 'd4, 53, oe54, 54d4' and other scancodes, nothing work.
With other keys all work fine, its remapped successful.
How i can find actual scancodes of this keys?